# At what level is the Android Camera2 API supported on the Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, galaxy, android-camera2

Phones have varying levels of support for the Android Camera2 API. The three levels of support are FULL, LIMITED and LEGACY.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html

What is the level of support for this API on the Samsung Galaxy S7, Galaxy S7 Edge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote a small program to check the level of support for both the front and rear camera on the Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.

Rear: FULL camera2 API support
Front: LIMITED support